# unable to save venue field

Tags: python, django

**model.py**

```
class venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Venue name',max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    zip_code = models.CharField('zip/post code',max_length=120)
    phone = models.CharField('contact phone',max_length=20, blank=True)
    web = models.URLField('web Address', blank=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField('Email Address', blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import venue
admin.site.register(venue)
```

[unable to save data into fields, its occuring OperationErrors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jphsz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after creating this model? `no such table` means that your database is currently lacking the expected tables.

Comment: yes I've ran both the commands, still It's shownig the same error.